# To tell browser to set the key Overwrite/Insert mode

Tags: keyboard, browser, default-settings

How, on Linux, can we set back and forth between key Overwrite/Insert mode in web browser preferably chromium one ?

Comment: You mean other than by pressing the Insert key? What platform are you on?

Comment: Still; "Other than by the Insert key?" This might actually depend on what I consider be "webcrap" - bad coding in web applications.